# Why is const redundant when using const functions C++?

Tags: c++, constants

So all modifiers that I have come across in C++ have came prior to the name of the function. Why is const different? Why must it both precede the name and come prior to the function block?

```
const int getSize() const;
```

or

```
const int getSize const {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These are 2 different usages of the `const` keyword.

In this case:

```
const int getSize() {
```

the function is returning an `int` that is `const`, i.e. the return value cannot be modified. This is not very useful, since the `const` in the return value is going to be ignored (compilers will warn about this). `const` in the return type is only useful when returning a `const*`, or a `const&`.

In this case:

```
int getSize() const {
```

this is a const-qualified member function, i.e. this member function can be called on `const` objects. Also, this guarantees that the object will not be modified, even if it's non-const.

Of course, you can use both of these together:

```
const int getSize() const {
```

which is a const-qualified member function that returns a `const int`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Forgive my stupidity, but const after means that the function does not mutate object data?

Comment: *This is not very useful, since the return value is likely to be copied anyway* It’s even worse. That `const` is completely useless  because a `const` on a returned value is ignored. There are even compiler warnings for it. `const` as a part of the return type only makes sense as a *pointer to const* or *reference to const*.

Answer (score 1):

The const before the function is applied to the return type of the function.  The const after is only for member functions and means that the member function is callable on a const object.

As a note returning a const int does not make sense, many compilers will warn that the const gets discarded.